# Get Vimeo Id Using Embed Source -- JavaScript/Jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, regex, vimeo

I want to get the Id of a **Vimeo** video using its Embed Source.

I want it in **JavaScript** OR **jQuery**.

I am using below code to do the same in **PHP**.

```
preg_match('/player\.vimeo\.com\/video\/([0-9]*)/', $embed, $match);

$vid = $match[1];
```

The above one is working fine. Is It possible to use above regex in javascript?

Here is a sample vimeo embed source -

```
<iframe src="http://player.vimeo.com/video/51478122?title=0&amp;byline=0&amp;portrait=0&amp;color=fcfcfc" width="500" height="281" frameborder="0" webkitAllowFullScreen mozallowfullscreen allowFullScreen></iframe> <p><a href="http://vimeo.com/51478122">Dum Spiro - HD (ESMA 2012)</a> from <a href="http://vimeo.com/dumspiro">Dum Spiro</a> on <a href="http://vimeo.com">Vimeo</a>.</p>
```

I want to extract `51478122` from this.

Any Help?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sure, JavaScript supports regex as well >>

```
var match = embed.match(/player\.vimeo\.com\/video\/([0-9]*)/);
```

[jsfiddle.net/XUDBL](http://jsfiddle.net/XUDBL)

Comment: how do i extract id using this?

Comment: I would suggest to use regex `\bhttp:\/\/player\.vimeo\.com\/video\/(\d+)`

Answer (score 0):

As per your requirement I am fetching src from Iframe and extracting the Vimeo video Id. Solved using jQuery

please have a look.

**DEMO**

http://jsfiddle.net/saorabhkr/XKvY6/1/

Comment: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/149890/prevent-posts-with-links-to-jsfiddle-and-no-code http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/84342/answer-that-only-contains-a-link-to-jsfiddle